# Excel formula only working on first cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have  formula i'm trying to use to give me a list of missing items between two cells. For some reason it will only work on the first row but not the rest. If I type in the values manually in the second row, it will work, but that's not an option. I've tried to close and open the workbook and various F9 combinations. Nothing seems to work.

[image]

Formula: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,[Site Collection Groups],0)),A2,"")`

Comment: hard to say without a sample file-perhaps there are trailing spaces? if so try `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(TRIM(A2),[Site Collection Groups],0)),A2,"")`

Comment: I don't think it's trim, from what I can see they are identical.

Comment: What I ended up doing is using =trim(b2) then copied over the same cell the values only. From there I just used conditional formating to find duplicates :/

Answer (score 0):

First, delete everything in the missing groups column (or copy it somewhere else, just in case).

then enter this formula in C2

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(TRIM([@[All Groups]]),TRIM([Site Collection Groups]),0)),TRIM([@[All Groups]]),"")
```

Then press ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of just enter)

This will trim both the single entry for column A and all of the entries for column B. It also uses table references for everything (instead of referencing A2, etc).